# Code in Github is not the same as code on production server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, github

I have inherited a project which was previously outsourced to a web development company. It's a typical MEAN website.

I was unable to get the code working from the Github repository, so I downloaded the code from the production server, did an *npm rebuild* and voila, it works.

This leads me to believe the code in Github is not the same as the code on the production server. This is a real possibility, as the outsourced company who built the product were awful. As an example, they hadn't even heard of the concept of a technical specification.

I know I can just start diff'ing every file to see what's different, and then correct the Github repository, but I'm wondering if you know of a better way to handle this? For example, is there an easier way to see the differences without doing a million diffs?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: does production have .git folder?

Comment: With WinMerge you can diff folders and sub-folders and list only the files that are different.

Answer (score 1):

I am using FileMerge on OSX to easily see the differences.

*Yep*, the outsourced company who made our software were doing updates on productions and not committing them to GitHub. Grrr!